# startx (xinit) not working

Tags: server, xorg, virtualization, 18.10, xinit

So I am installing Ubuntu Server (18.10) in a VirtualBox VM and it's working, except that I can't get startx to work. I'd like to have i3wm, because it good for multitasking and it's light.

The install is almost new all I've done is installed a few packages (clang, build-essentials, linux-headers and a few others) and VBoxAdditions. The Ubuntu install itself also has nothing custom, I haven't installed any of the packages it allows you to install during the installation. Only thing that is diffrent from the default is that I used LVM (`ubuntu-lv` (`/` mount) is 70GB which should be more than enough).

So then I installed `startx` and `i3`. After doing that and rebooting `startx` didn't work and gave me a log. https://pastebin.com/mY36rJH3

I have tried removing the `.Xauthority` file and chmod'ing it with 777, neither worked. I noticed that when I delete it it recreates it with only `-rw-------` (I'm **not** doing `sudo startx`) I have tried purging and installing both xinit and i3, which again didn't work.

Host machine:
i7-6700K
R9 290
16GB RAM (10GB to the guest)
Windows 10

Hardware Virtualization and 3D Acceleration are enabled. Video memory is 128MB.

If I could help by giving anything else just tell me in the comments, please. Thanks for your time!

Comment: This maybe? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1711995

Comment: @steeldriver So I should just dpkg-divert --rename /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so ? How exactly does that command work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to fix it - I just hoped the linked bug report might lead you to a solution